# counting unbeaten games n Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm creating a dataset for the FiFa worldcup 2022 and I'm trying to create a column that counts the number of matches a given country is unbeaten (i.e. has only won or drawn in previous matches) before the start of a given match.

I've been trying to get the logic going using a counter that loops over a list of results, but I can't get it to work on a team level.

My desired output would look something like this:

| Date | Team | Result | Desired output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-27 | NL | lose |  |
| 2021-09-01 | NL | win | 0 |
| 2021-09-04 | NL | win | 1 |
| 2021-09-08 | NL | win | 2 |
| 2021-09-15 | NL | draw | 3 |
| 2021-09-18 | NL | Lose | 4 |
| 2021-10-01 | NL | Win | 0 |
| 2021-10-05 | NL | Win | 1 |
| 2021-06-27 | UK | lose |  |
| 2021-09-01 | NL | win | 0 |
| 2021-09-04 | UK | draw | 1 |
| 2021-08-27 | UK | lose | 2 |
| 2021-08-31 | UK | win | 0 |

Comment: why does NL reset to 0 on `2021-09-01`? it was still unbeaten

Comment: NL lost a game on  2021-06-27 so at the next game on 2021-09-01, it had zero won/drawn matches before they started the game.

Comment: so there are only 2 teams and UK wins equals NL loses?

Comment: No, there are > 200 countries. On every date there will be at least two countries playing (i.e. against each other), but there could be multiple matches on the same date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the provided output is incorrect as NL is still unbeaten on `2021-09-01`.

I would thus use:

```
group = df['Result'][::-1].str.lower().eq('lose').groupby(df['Team']).cumsum()

df['days_unbeaten'] = df.groupby([df['Team'], group]).cumcount()
```

output:

```
          Date Team Result  Desired output  days_unbeaten
0   2021-06-27   NL   lose             NaN              0
1   2021-09-01   NL    win             0.0              0
2   2021-09-04   NL    win             1.0              1
3   2021-09-08   NL    win             2.0              2
4   2021-09-15   NL   draw             3.0              3
5   2021-09-18   NL   Lose             4.0              4
6   2021-10-01   NL    Win             0.0              0
7   2021-10-05   NL    Win             1.0              1
8   2021-06-27   UK   lose             NaN              0
9   2021-09-01   NL    win             0.0              2
10  2021-09-04   UK   draw             1.0              0
11  2021-08-27   UK   lose             2.0              1
12  2021-08-31   UK    win             0.0              0
```

Comment: Great! This works very well for the example I shared, but when I use it on my entire dataset, I get the following error when I try to run the group command: ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels. Do you have a suggestion to work around this error?

Comment: Do you still have the error when not assigning? i.e. just running `df.groupby([df['Team'], group]).cumcount()`?

Comment: No, I don't get the error when I run  group = df.groupby([df['team']]).cumcount(). HOwever, when I then create the ['days_unbeate'], I get a zero everywhere.... I hope I ran the right code, because I wasn't quite sure how to interpret the ['Team'], group] part.

Comment: This means that you have duplicates in the index. Either solve this or use `df['days_unbeaten'] = df.groupby([df['Team'], group]).cumcount().values`